# Syntax error: unexpected end of file. Bash

Tags: bash, syntax, teamspeak

I want to set up a teamspeak bot, and I have this script to start this.

```
    #!/bin/bash
    if [ $1 = 'stop' ] 
      then 
        echo stop >> /root/ts3bot/tmp/log.txt
      date >>/root/ts3bot/tmp/log.txt
        echo ======================
        screen -S bot -X quit
      fi

    if [ $1 = 'start' ] 
      then 
      echo start >> /root/ts3bot/tmp/log.txt
      date >> /root/ts3bot/tmp/log.txt
      echo ======================
        screen -dmS bot php core.php
        ps ax | grep -v grep | grep -v -i SCREEN | grep links >> /root/ts3bot/tmp/log.txt
    fi
     <here is an extra blank line>
```

but when I type `bash bot.sh` it says `syntax error: unexpected end of file`
I don't know what I did wrong :/ the chmod is set on `755`

Thanks!

Comment: Pasting the code in http://www.shellcheck.net/ reveals some errors. You may want to check this before going any further

Comment: @fedorqui: apart from double quotes around `$1` and the suggestion to use `pgrep`, shellcheck.net is returning false errors.

Comment: Check your file for special characters: `cat --show-nonprinting bot.sh`

Comment: Doesn't bash give you the line number just before the `syntax error`?

Comment: oh I forgot to tell u about that. its in this blank line. If I delete it, I will get error in line with "fi"

Comment: Did you download this script to a Windows box, and then copy it over to a Linux server?

Comment: The script has $1 expecting an argument but your just running bash bot.sh without an extra argument. Does bash bot.sh start work?

Comment: @AndreaCorbellini true, it is weird however. Thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 3):

I suspect you may have copied this shell script from a Microsoft Windows box over to a Linux or Unix server.  If so, the problem might be that you have DOS/Windows line endings, which can cause unpredictable results in scripts.

To check the script for bad line endings on a Linux or Unix server, you can dump the file (sort of like a hex dump) by typing the following at the shell prompt:

```
$ od -c bot.sh | less
```

And look for `\n` or `\r` or `\r\n`.  If lines appear to have a `\r` at the end, then you've found the problem.

To FIX this line-ending problem, you can use a tool like `dos2unix` if it's installed on your system.  If you don't have `dos2unix` but you're on a Linux server, you may be able to do this instead:

```
$ sed -i 's/\r//' bot.sh
```

to convert the file.

Lastly ... see the first line of the script, `#!/bin/bash`?  Because of that, you don't need to run this with `bash bot.sh`, you can just execute it directly with `./bot.sh`.

Comment: I can confirm that using DOS line endings produces a syntax error.